# 100 parallel lines in a plane divide that plane into how many parts?

Tags: geometry

I developed a formula for the number of parts which $n$ parallel lines divide a plane into, not sure if it's right:
$$\frac{n(n+3)}2$$ and so I get the number 5150, but in my solutions at the end of the book I found that the answer is 200. How can this be? Is my formula wrong or is the book's solution wrong?

Comment: Have you tried sketching this? Not with a 100 parallel lies but say 1, 2 and 3 how many parts do you get? Can you see a pattern forming? I would think both are wrong. 1 line splits the plane in two a second line splits one of these smaller planes in 2 making 3 in total doesn't it?

Comment: @WarrenHill Yes I figured that the number is just $n+1$, but shouldn't you count the larger parts too, as such:https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/262219771125301258/377167952820043777/5_delova.png?width=768&height=350

Comment: This would not be my interpretation of the question as asked but assuming it is (and it would be a  more interesting question) with one line we still have the original plane and two sub-planes making three in total.  So what you have does not work for \$n = 0\$ or \$n=1\$

Answer (score 1):

I don't get either solution. The lines are parallel. 
So it would look likes this for five lines $$\ | \ | \ | \ | \ | \ $$

One part at the right, one at the left, and $4$ in between.
So for $100$ line, $101$ parts.

Comment: If they are pairwise distinct. :-) In the opposite case, 101 is the maximum.

Comment: Good point. But if the lines are not distinct why would the parts need to be. :-)

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-You are not right. One / divides the plane into 2 parts;2 //'s into 3 parts and so on. The induction is immediate: n parallels divide the plane into n+1 parts.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a way to get the answer $200$, but it requires a rather odd interpretation of the question. If we ask, how many different *half-planes* are determined by $100$ parallel lines, the answer is $200$.

It may be a little easier to see if we come down a dimension, and ask how many different rays are determined by $100$ points on a number line. Let the points be $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_{100}$. Then they determine the rays $(-\infty,a_1],(-\infty,a_2],\dots,(-\infty,a_{100}],[a_1,\infty),[a_2,\infty),\dots,[a_{100},\infty)$; $200$ rays in all. Now just go up a dimension and count half-planes the same way.